How to add chromadb to Kernel
I am trying to add chromadb to the kernel. Based on the docs:
09-memory-with-chroma it should be as easy as
var chromaMemoryStore = new ChromaMemoryStore("http://127.0.0.1:8000");
builder.WithMemoryStorage(chromaMemoryStore);
var kernel = builder.Build();

but WithMemoryStorage does not exist.
I am using the latest packages:
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" Version="5.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.SemanticKernel" Version="1.18.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.SemanticKernel.Abstractions" Version="1.18.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.SemanticKernel.Connectors.Chroma" Version="1.18.2-alpha" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.SemanticKernel.Connectors.OpenAI" Version="1.18.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.SemanticKernel.Core" Version="1.18.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.SemanticKernel.Plugins.Core" Version="1.18.2-alpha" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.SemanticKernel.Plugins.Memory" Version="1.18.2-alpha" />
  </ItemGroup>


It turns out that WithMemoryStorage is no longer available.
I managed to find a way to use chromadb with semantic kernel using kernel memory
var builder = Kernel
    .CreateBuilder()
    .AddOpenAIChatCompletion(modelId, endpoint, null);

// use a local embedding model
builder.AddBertOnnxTextEmbeddingGeneration(@"C:\temp\model.onnx", @"C:\temp\vocab.txt");

builder.Services.AddLogging(c => c.AddConsole());
var kernel = builder.Build();

var embedding = kernel.GetRequiredService<ITextEmbeddingGenerationService>();
var vectorStore = new ChromaMemoryStore("http://localhost:8000");
var memory = new SemanticTextMemory(vectorStore, embedding);
string chromacollection = "test";

kernel.ImportPluginFromObject(new TextMemoryPlugin(memory));

string template = @" Answer then question: {{$input}}
                    based on the input: {{Recall}}";

here is the sample usage:
while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Question:");
    var question = Console.ReadLine()!;

    Console.WriteLine("Debug VectorDb:");
    await foreach (var item in memory.SearchAsync(chromacollection, question, 3))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Metadata.AdditionalMetadata);
        Console.WriteLine(item.Metadata.Text);
    }

    OpenAIPromptExecutionSettings executionSettings = new()
    {
        ToolCallBehavior = ToolCallBehavior.EnableKernelFunctions
    };

    var response = kernel.InvokePromptStreamingAsync(template,
        arguments: new KernelArguments(executionSettings)
        {
            {"input", question},
            {"collection", chromacollection}
        }
    );

    Console.WriteLine("LLM:");
    await foreach (var message in response)
    {
        Console.Write(message);
    }
}

